# A group of 40 people consists of 20 women and 20 men. How many ways are there to form 12 pairs from the group?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

An answer I've been given is:

$\frac{1}{12!}[(40C2)(38C2)(36C2)(34C2)(32C2)(30C2)(28C2)(26C2)(24C2)(22C2)]$

Which I don't fully understand.

Why the answer stops at 22 and doesn't go all the way to 18 doesn't make sense.

I can make sense of the $\frac{1}{12!}$ multiplication but I'm not 100% sure why it's necessary.  I've stumbled upon other answers that mention labeled vs unlabeled, could someone provide an example of a question where the $\frac{1}{12!}$ isn't necessary?

Comment: You are correct that the stated answer should be multiplied by $\binom{20}{2}\binom{18}{2}$.  The factor of $\frac{1}{12!}$ is used to account for the fact that the order of selection does not matter.

Comment: In the answer you were given you are also counting pairs of two men or two women. Are you supposed to count them too? Otherwise there is no reason to distinguish between them in the statement of the problem.